# Does Encog C# support 64 bits?

Tags: encog

Does Encog C# support 64 bits ?

I can compile in 32 bits with Encog but I can not compile in 64 bits ?

How can we compile in 64 bits with Encog ?

Comment: I could not find anything on this specifically  but this is the google search: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Encog%22+C%23+support+64+bits&oq=%22Encog%22+C%23+support+64+bits 
 There are a few pdf's at the start, and a few questions relating to this.

Comment: I was testing an example "encog-sample-csharp". it was using a 32 bits Encog DLL. This is why I could not compile in 64 bits.

With the example "Encog-dotnet-core-3.3.0", we can compile in 64 bits 

It work fine in 64 bits

Answer (score 0):

The Encog core DLL can be compiled to either 64 or 32 bits.  Unlike the Java Encog version, you have to specifically target one.